# Como mostrar en JOptionPane, un tributo de un enum

Tags: java, string, enum

estoy urilizando enums y JOptioPane, y quiero mostrar el atributo del enum, (osea un string), esto es lo que tengo:

```
public Cities readCityOrigen() {
    Cities [] listCityOrigen = Cities.values();
    Cities city = (Cities) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "Seleccione la ciudad de origen del vuelo",
            "CIUDAD DE ORIGEN", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
            null, listCityOrigen, listCityOrigen[0]);
        return city;
}`

package models;

 public enum Cities {
  BOGOTA ("Bogota"),
  CALI ("Cali"),
  BUCARAMNAGA ("Bucaramanga"),
  CARTAGENA("Cartagena"),
  SANTA_MARTA("Santa Marta"),
  MEDELLIN("Medellin"),
  TUNJA("Tunja"),
  PEREIRA("Pererira"),
  ARMENIA("Armenia"),
  RIOHACHA("Riohacha"),
  TOKYO("Tokio"),
  CARACAS("Caracas"),
  PARIS("Paris"),
  NEW_YORK("Nueva Yotk"),
  MIAMI("Maimi"),
 MADRID("Madrid");

String  cities;
Cities(String cities){
    this.cities = cities;
}
public String getCities(){
    return this.cities;
}
}
```

quiero que en el JOptionPane salga el string, pero me sale el literal del atributo

Answer (score 2):

Una solución sería dentro de su clase `Cities` Implementar su método [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString()) para devolver el nombre dado a sus constantes

```
public enum Cities {
 /* el resto del código */

/* Agregar el método toString*/
@Override
public String toString() {
    return cities;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que podrías poner dentro del enumerado *Cities*, el método `toString()`, y modificar el método para que te reemplace todas las letras a minúscula, excepto la primera y reemplazar todas las `"_"` por espacios, así:

```
public enum Command {
    BOGOTA,CALI,BUCARAMNAGA,CARTAGENA,SANTA_MARTA,MEDELLIN,TUNJA,PEREIRA,ARMENIA,RI_HACHA,TOKYO,CARACAS,PARIS,NEW_YORK,MIAMI,MADRID;


@Override
public String toString() {
    //cambiamos todos los "_" por espacios en blanco y cambiamos las letras 
    //minusculas con toLowerCase y concatenamos el resto
    String name = name().replaceAll("_", " ").toLowerCase();
    //la primer letra la ponemos en mayuscula con toUpperCase
    name = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
    return name;
   }
}
```